# Group (By) in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I've constructed the query I want in the shell but am having trouble writing it in Mongoose.

```
db.commentstreams.group({ key: { page_id: true }, reduce: function(obj,prev) { prev.num_comments += obj.num_comments }, initial: { num_comments: 0 } })
```

I'm a bit confused by the Mongoose syntax; perhaps someone could shed some light on this one. Much thanks.

Answer (score 15):

According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/mongoose-orm/browse_thread/thread/58adc5dd5f419a27/b9ea01b0f11723f4?lnk=gst&q=group#b9ea01b0f11723f4):

```
Model.find({}, [fields], {'group': 'FIELD'}, function(err, logs) { 
        ... 
});
```

Unfortunately we seem to be lacking documentation for this one.

Comment: This does not seem to work - it returns all document as doing an empty find.

Comment: $group instead of group?

Answer (score 13):

MapReduce should be the proper way to go but if you're not sharding and your query won't result in more than 10k records its ok.

You can access any node-mongodb-native functions through moongoose, so it looks like this:

```
var group = {
   key: {},
   cond: {item_id: item_id},
   reduce: function(doc, out) {
      out.count++;
      out.total += doc.value;
   },
   initial: {
       total: 0,
       count: 0
   },
   finalize: function(out) {
       out.avg = out.total / out.count;
   }
};

Item.collection.group(group.key, group.cond, group.initial, group.reduce, group.finalize, true, function(err, results) {
    console.log('group results %j', results);
});
```

node-mongodb-native source: 
https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/collection.js#L1165

MongoDB group doc:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to use Mongoose to group maybe you're better take a look at this
[Mongoose group query in node.js / express route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26802632/5732720)

It seems group is not supported by Mongoose while aggregate is.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with similar example, I hope this be helpful

```
Register.aggregate(
[
  {
   $group: {_id: {campaign: "$campaign"}, quantity: {$sum: 1}}
},
  {
    $limit: 5
  },
  {
    $sort: {date: -1}
  }
], function (err, res) {
        console.log(res)
});
```