# Mongoose group query in node.js / express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello i have the following query that executed in Robomongo works as expected:

```
db.av.group(
{
 key: { roomId: 1},
 cond: { dateOfDay: { $gte: new Date('12/01/2014'), $lt: new Date('12/30/2014') } },
 reduce: function( curr, result ) {
            result.total += curr.price;
            result.count++;
         },
 initial: { total : 0,
     count : 0
     },
     finalize: function(result) {
              result.avg = Math.round(result.total / result.count);
          }

  }
)
```

After implemented that in a express app :

```
 app.get('/api/checkAv/:checkIn/:checkOut', function(req, res) {
        var checkIn = req.params.checkIn,
            checkOut = req.params.checkOut,
            roomType = req.params.roomType;

    model.Av.group(
    {
     key: { roomId: 1},
     cond: { dateOfDay: { $gte: new Date('12/01/2014'), $lt: new Date('12/30/2014') } },
     reduce: function( curr, result ) {
                result.total += curr.price;
                result.count++;
             },
     initial: { total : 0,
         count : 0
         },
         finalize: function(result) {
                  result.avg = Math.round(result.total / result.count);
              }

    }

    ).exec(function(err, av) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(av);
    });
});
```

i get on the console :

> TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {    if (!(this
>   instanceof model))
>        return new model(doc, fields, skipId);    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);  } has no method 'group'    at
>   /home/www/domain.com/api/routes/routes.js:58:18    at Layer.handle [as
>   handle_request]
>   (/home/www/domain.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>   at next
>   (/home/www/domain.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:13)
>   at Route.dispatch
>   (/home/www/domain.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:81:3)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (/home/www/domain.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>   at
>   /home/www/brasovapartments.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:234:24
>   at param
>   (/home/www/domain.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:331:14)
>   at param
>   (/home/www/domain.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:347:14)
>   at param
>   (/home/www/domain.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:347:14)
>   at Function.proto.process_params
>   (/home/www/domain.com/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:391:3)

now reading around i saw some people defined a group property but not sure how and where .. in the Mongoose schema?
Can you gave me a hint what's my problem over-here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/#db.collection.group) command isn't supported by Mongoose, and was also deprecated in MongoDB 3.4 as its functionality is better served by using [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) instead.

You can do this with `aggregate` using something like:

```
model.Av.aggregate([
    {$match: {dateOfDay: {$gte: new Date('12/01/2014'), $lt:new Date('12/30/2014')}}},
    {$group: {
        _id: '$roomId',
        total: {$sum: '$price'},
        count: {$sum: 1},
        avg: {$avg: '$price'}
    }}
], function (err, result) {...});
```

You can omit the `total` and `count` fields if you don't need them as the [`$avg`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) operator lets you calculate the average price directly.

Comment: Actually you can. Look at this. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/

Comment: @AkarshSatija Sure, MongoDB supports it, but the Mongoose library doesn't have support for it. That's the same link that's in my answer. :-)

Comment: @godzsa Yes; even more so now as the `group` command is deprecated since 3.4.